# Radeon X1550 problem

Tags: ati, graphics

I'm new to Ubuntu and tried read some similar Q&A without success. I have an old computer - Athlon 3000 XP, motherboard Gigabyte GA 7N 400 pro2, ATI Radeon X1550, 1.8 GB RAM. Istalled Ubuntu 11.10 today and performance is not great. Basically desktop effects are slow, and online videos freeze or are choppy. I've tried sudo apt-get install fglrx command and it improved a bit, but when trying to get to catalyst I'm getting following message: "There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.  It could be caused by the following.
No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly.
Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig" anticonfig say that there's no recognised device. Please help

Comment: What's the output of `glxinfo | grep render` ?

Comment: The program 'glxinfo' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

Comment: direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,

Comment: sorry that was without fglrx, with that installed it is now: X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  135 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12

Comment: I was just about to post that your card is not supported any more by fglrx. What's the output of `sudo aptitude show fglrx | grep State` ?

Comment: thats not good, the output: sudo: aptitude: command not found. i am a complete linux ignorant....

Comment: should i remove fglrx then?

Answer (score 1):

Your ati card is not supported by fglrx any more.
Please remove fglrx. Now, to be on the safe side, you have to reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri and libgl1-mesa-glx:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
```

To get better performance with unity, please try unity2d (you can select unity2d by logging out and choosing unity2d in ubuntu's greeter window:
[image]

Just click on that gear thingy and you can choose unity2d.

Comment: Ah, came on, Linux is great, it really is. Just give it a shot! You could also try the lubuntu-desktop, (sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop), a desktop environment designed especially for older hardware. With your specs it should fly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php?title=Radeon_x1550&redirect=no

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/install-ati-official-drivers-in-ubuntu/)
is a link on how to install the official ATI drivers.
And check if your hardware is [supported](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware)